# DownloadManager not working without internet connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-download-manager

I am trying to write an app that allows me to connect to my Olympus camera through wifi, and use it's built-in server to pull my raw images from it. My problem is that, when I'm on the camera's wifi, downloadManager doesn't seem to work, only when I connect my phone to the web. Am I missing something here, or is this tool really not fit for this task?

My DownloadManager:

```
public void getImage(String imageName, Context context) {
    File file = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString(), imageName);

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.10/DCIM/100OLYMP/" + imageName))
            .setTitle(imageName + ": OlyRaw Image")
            .setDescription("Downloading")
            .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM, imageName)
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .addRequestHeader("user-agent", "OlympusCameraKit")
            .addRequestHeader("host", "192.168.0.10")
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);

    Log.d("Response", "http://192.168.0.10/DCIM/100OLYMP/" + imageName);

    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    try{
        downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(downloadId));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Response", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: It starts the download, but is stuck in "waiting for connection" phase. When I connect to the web, it goes to "Retry", since it didn't find the specified endpoint.

Comment: I did some test where DownloadManager had to download from a server on the phone itself. It did not go when wifi was off. It did not go when wifi was not connected to a router. Will try without internet later... Is big brother watching us??? Can you tell type of Olympus camera? How do you know the filename(s)? Are there commands to list a directory?

Comment: Devices have to ping somewhere on the web to determine that current connection is actually internet capable, it's not even exclusive to phones. I'd assume download manager is waiting for that ping to succeed so device enters "online" state. I don't believe there's an option for download manager to operate purely within local network (there are question from 2019 without answer), you'll need to look for third party solutions.

Comment: @blackapps it's an om d em-10 mark II camera and yeah, there is a command to list each photo taken.

Comment: `Devices have to ping somewhere on the web to determine that current connection is actually internet capable,` @Pawel. Not the device but some software called DownloadManager. Well there is not any need to have internet as other client and server apps just work in local w(lan) or with wifi direct without needing internet. Its a terribke 'feature'.

Comment: But no big problem. Throw away DownloadManager. There are plenty of other solutions. Ten code lines will do.

Comment: @blackapps I'm not going to say I'm certain because that'd require specific knowledge of ASOP source but since download manager is a system service I assume it hooks into the same "device online state" as other system components rather than pinging something itself hence calling it a "device ping" is not wrong.

Comment: @Pawel. Ok. But i see no reason for checking internet connection if it is a local address.

Comment: @blackapps download manager only gives each download a bunch of retries before its considered failed so it doesn't even try unless it determines device is online and those tries have a chance to succeed. Sadly local addresses are a victim of this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue : as soon as I use my mobile as a hotspot, DownloadManager is not working. I get a download failure notification with no additional information.
There is nothing in the intent get in onReceive method of the registered BroadcastReceiver.
I works like a charm if the 2 devices are connected to my home WIFI......

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).