# Downloading unusual file types on Android, Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, download, mime-types

I'm trying to write an Android app that connects to a wifi enabled Olympus camera and pulls the RAW (.ORF) files from it. My question is, how can I save the recieved "octet-stream" type response in the said format?
I [tried with DownloadManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674758/downloadmanager-not-working-without-internet-connection?noredirect=1#comment124939797_70674758), but for other reasons it's not a viable method. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question about file types, it seems like an issue about the nature of your device's connection.  When transferring files, you don't need to care about the file type.

Comment: There are other ways to download files, but they will probably fail in the same way as DownloadManager does.   Are your Android device and camera both connected to the same Wifi network?

Comment: @Stephen C the camera acts as an access point, so it yeah, the phone is using the wifi provided by the camera.

Comment: And you are sure that the Android device has successfully connected to that Wifi network and packets are being routed correctly, and you are attempting to use the correct IP and port when the android device attempts to download?

Comment: Yes, tried it with postman and in browser (both on pc and mobile) with the same settings, and it worked.